# Looking through RecordSet and creating JSON output with Dictionary

Tags: json, vb.net, for-loop, serialization, dictionary

I'm trying to make a JSON output (return value) from a query a user sends to a Web Service.

The code I am currently using to do this is (just for a test):

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim sqlSelect As String = "firstName, lastName, email" '3 field names to search by
    Dim _count As Integer = 2 'Has 2 records returned
    Dim _QueryData As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Dim _Fields As String() = sqlSelect.Split(",")

    For _int As Integer = 0 To _count - 1
       For index As Integer = 0 To _Fields.Count - 1
           _QueryData.Add(_Fields(index).Trim, "something" & index)
       Next
    Next

Console.WriteLine(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                  _QueryData,
                  Formatting.Indented)
                  )
End Sub
```

Now there is a problem here that I can think of:

(1) Using a Dictionary I am limited to only one "key" so once it loops again for the second record, it will give an error of that "key" already being present. But without the same fields ("key") for the next record, it wouldn't be a JSON string...

How can I modify the code in order to get it working the way I need it to?

I could do it manually like so:

```
 Dim sqlSelect As String = "firstName, lastName, email" '3 field names to search by
 Dim _count As Integer = 2 'Has 2 records returned
 Dim _QueryData As String = "{"
 Dim _Fields As String() = sqlSelect.Split(",")

 For _int As Integer = 0 To _count - 1
    If _int >= 1 Then _QueryData &= "," & vbCrLf & "{" & vbCrLf

    For index As Integer = 0 To _Fields.Count - 1
       _QueryData &= """" & _Fields(index).Trim & """" & ":" & """" & "something" & index & """," & vbCrLf
    Next

    _QueryData = _QueryData.Substring(0, _QueryData.Length - 3) & vbCrLf & "}"
 Next
```

Which produces:

```
{
 "firstName":"something0",
 "lastName":"something1",
 "email":"something2"
},
{
 "firstName":"something0",
 "lastName":"something1",
 "email":"something2"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are executing a query, you ought to be able to read that to a datatable, which then allows for simple serialization:

```
    Dim sJSONObject As String
    Dim sqlSelect As String = "firstName,lastName,email" '3 field names to search by
    Dim _count As Integer = 2 'Has 2 records returned
    Dim _QueryData As New DataTable()
    Dim _Fields As String() = sqlSelect.Split(",")
    Dim arrData As String()

    For Each sFieldName In _Fields
        _QueryData.Columns.Add(sFieldName)
    Next

    For _int As Integer = 0 To _count - 1
        ReDim arrData(_Fields.Count - 1)
        For index As Integer = 0 To _Fields.Count - 1
            arrData(index) = "something" & index
        Next
        _QueryData.Rows.Add(arrData)
    Next

    sJSONObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                      _QueryData, Formatting.Indented)
```

This results in:

```
[{
"firstName": "something0",
"lastName": "something1",
"email": "something2"
},
{
"firstName": "something0",
"lastName": "something1",
"email": "something2"
}]
```

If the square braces are a problem, simply trim them off before sending